# update/set maxcpc on one specific shopping product in an adgroup

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to update my max cpc bid for a specific product in adwords. 
Via the webui of adwords this is a trivial task, but I cant get it to work in code, this is what I have so far.

```
import com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.factory.AdWordsServices;
import com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201607.cm.*;
import com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsSession;
import com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OfflineCredentials;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
public class ChangeBidOnSpecificProduct {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OfflineCredentials build = new OfflineCredentials.Builder()
            .forApi(OfflineCredentials.Api.ADWORDS)
            .fromFile()
            .build();
    Credential oAuth2Credential = build
            .generateCredential();

    // Construct an AdWordsSession.
    AdWordsSession session = new AdWordsSession.Builder()
            .fromFile()
            .withOAuth2Credential(oAuth2Credential)
            .build();
    String accountId = "ACCOUNT_ID";
    Long campaignId = Long.valueOf("CAMPAIGN_ID");
    long adGroupId = Long.valueOf("ADGROUP_ID");
    session.setClientCustomerId(accountId);
    Money money = new Money(null, 40000L);
    String productId = "9200000050670959";
    changeBidViaApi(session, campaignId, adGroupId, productId, money);
}

private static void changeBidViaApi(AdWordsSession session, Long campaignId, long adGroupId, String productId, Money newValue) throws RemoteException {
    ProductOfferId productOfferId = new ProductOfferId();
    productOfferId.setValue(productId);
    ProductScope productScope = new ProductScope();
    productScope.setDimensions(new ProductDimension[] {productOfferId});

    BiddableAdGroupCriterion biddableAdGroupCriterion = new BiddableAdGroupCriterion();
    biddableAdGroupCriterion.setAdGroupId(adGroupId);
    biddableAdGroupCriterion.setCriterion(productScope);

    BiddingStrategyConfiguration biddingStrategyConfiguration = new BiddingStrategyConfiguration();
    CpcBid bid = new CpcBid();
    bid.setBid(newValue);
    biddingStrategyConfiguration.setBids(new Bids[]{bid});
    biddableAdGroupCriterion.setBiddingStrategyConfiguration(biddingStrategyConfiguration);

    AdGroupCriterionOperation operation = new AdGroupCriterionOperation();
    operation.setOperand(biddableAdGroupCriterion);
    operation.setOperator(Operator.SET);

    AdGroupCriterionOperation[] operations = new AdGroupCriterionOperation[]{operation};

    AdWordsServices adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
    AdGroupCriterionServiceInterface adGroupCriterionService =
            adWordsServices.get(session, AdGroupCriterionServiceInterface.class);
    AdGroupCriterionReturnValue result = adGroupCriterionService.mutate(operations);
    }
}
```

Executing this results in an error: 'Unmarshalling Error: cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'ns2:ProductScope' to a type definition for element 'ns2:criterion''.

This is the (anonimized) data that is send to google:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:RequestHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201607">
        <ns1:clientCustomerId>ACCOUNT_ID</ns1:clientCustomerId>
        <ns1:developerToken>MY_DEV_TOKEN</ns1:developerToken>
        <ns1:userAgent>MY_UA</ns1:userAgent>
        <ns1:validateOnly>false</ns1:validateOnly>
        <ns1:partialFailure>false</ns1:partialFailure>
    </ns1:RequestHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <mutate xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201607">
        <operations>
            <operator>SET</operator>
            <operand xsi:type="ns2:BiddableAdGroupCriterion" xmlns:ns2="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201607">
                <ns2:adGroupId>ADGROUP_ID</ns2:adGroupId>
                <ns2:criterion xsi:type="ns2:ProductScope">
                    <ns2:dimensions xsi:type="ns2:ProductOfferId">
                        <ns2:value>9200000050670959</ns2:value>
                    </ns2:dimensions>
                </ns2:criterion>
                <ns2:biddingStrategyConfiguration>
                    <ns2:bids xsi:type="ns2:CpcBid">
                        <ns2:bid>
                            <ns2:microAmount>1</ns2:microAmount>
                        </ns2:bid>
                    </ns2:bids>
                </ns2:biddingStrategyConfiguration>
            </operand>
        </operations>
    </mutate>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any suggestions as the reason for the error or what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by accessing the adwords items as a graph, iterating it and changing it bid value when I find a match.

```
private static void changeBidViaApi(AdWordsSession session, long adGroupId, String productId, Money newValue) throws RemoteException {
    AdWordsServices adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
    ProductPartitionTree partitionTree =
            ProductPartitionTree.createAdGroupTree(adWordsServices, session, adGroupId);

    for (ProductPartitionNode node : partitionTree.getRoot().getChildren()) {
        ProductPartitionNode productPartitionNode = node.asBiddableUnit();
        try {
            ProductOfferId dimension = (ProductOfferId) productPartitionNode.getDimension();
            if (dimension != null) {
                String productIdInShopping = dimension.getValue();
                if (productId.equals(productIdInShopping)) {
                    Long newBid = newValue.getMicroAmount();
                    productPartitionNode.setBid(newBid);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    AdGroupCriterionServiceInterface adGroupCriterionService =
            adWordsServices.get(session, AdGroupCriterionServiceInterface.class);

    List<AdGroupCriterionOperation> mutateOperations = partitionTree.getMutateOperations();

    if (mutateOperations.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Nothing to do.");
    } else {
        adGroupCriterionService.mutate(mutateOperations.toArray(new AdGroupCriterionOperation[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working source code. It changes bid (max cpc) of product partition group. It is written in php, but you can modify this code to java.

```
$adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
$session = $this->getSession();
$adGroupCriterionService = $adWordsServices->get($session, AdGroupCriterionService::class);
$operations = [];
$adGroupCriterion = new BiddableAdGroupCriterion();
$adGroupCriterion->setAdGroupId(22122723325); // id of my adgroup
$adGroupCriterion->setCriterion(new Criterion(302190832)); // id of partition group. you can get find this id in PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT in ID field (which full name is Criterion ID)
//
$bid = new CpcBid();
$money = new Money();
$money->setMicroAmount(((float)4)*1000000);
$bid->setBid($money);
$biddingStrategyConfiguration = new BiddingStrategyConfiguration();
$biddingStrategyConfiguration->setBids([$bid]);
$adGroupCriterion->setBiddingStrategyConfiguration($biddingStrategyConfiguration);
$operation = new AdGroupCriterionOperation();
$operation->setOperand($adGroupCriterion);
$operation->setOperator(Operator::SET);
$operations[] = $operation;
//
$adGroupCriterionService->mutate($operations);
```